# How to CONCAT quotes while selecting any data from the table

Tags: sql, unix

The file (date.sql) has the below commands

```
date=2014-12-03   
SET VAR vDate $date  

insert into (Some_table) (date,location)  
select $vDate , location from (let say from table "Location")
```

while executing this sql script i am getting the below error as its expecting values like '2014-12-03' but here its coming without quotes

ERROR:Insert data type mismatch for column date

Is there anyway to concat ' before and after date or is there any simpler way to achieve it ???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you'd probably want `set vdate='2014-12-03'`, then `select @vDate`.

Comment: `DECLARE $vDate date = '2014-12-03';` ?

Comment: here i need to use the SET command only .. VDate should be set like   '2014-12-03' not like 2014-12-03 .. Any idea ?? .. Thanks for the quick reply Marc and jonathan

Comment: `sql` is about as generic as it gets. Yet most implementations have their and own and (somewhat) conflicting syntax to accomplish even this sort of simple task. Please add a tag for the type of SQL database that is giving you that `ERROR ...` message. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Shellter .. Let be simple my incoming data for the variable "date" is like date=2014-12-03 somehow i want to add single quotes before and after the date and want to set that in another variable in sql file .. Thanks in advance